# Getting Expected count of SQL query result beforehand?

Tags: sql, vba, teradata, adodb

I am making a UI which will take parameters from user and then generate a SQL query according to these parameters and then fetch records using ADODB connection.
I want to give a Flag in UI before submitting the parameters by user which will tell the expected number of records from the selected parameters.
How can I accomplish these?

My back-end is Teradata and assume that my UI is on Excel VBA

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You've got a good question here, but in order to really help you, we need to see some things you've *already tried*. What research have you conducted that led you to come here? Have you implemented any solutions that didn't work as expected that we might be able to troubleshoot? Have you already elected against any possibilities? Answering those sorts of questions will really help us all get to your answer sooner, and help other people who might be in a similar situation in the future find your question and, hopefully, your solution.

Comment: I have tried EXPLAIN statement, but the expected record count is too faulty to be trusted upon.

Answer (score 0):

The exact number or just an estimated one?

- estimated number:

You might run an EXPLAIN on your SELECT and extract the size of the last spool, it will look like "The size of Spool 34 is estimated with no confidence to be 897,418 rows (54,742,498 bytes)"

- exact number:

I can't tell about your ADODB connection, but Teradata's ODBC driver supports the SQLRowCount function and enhanced it to work with SELECTs, too. When you use ODBC and submit a SELECT you can get the number of rows returned beforehand.

Comment: I have tried Explain, but that is giving answer with no confidence.
For ex. For the query which is fetching me 1.46 million records, the Explain statement is giving 121 million records as expected output

Comment: Well, the estimation might be totally off, especially when the confidence is "no". Collecting statistics can help to increase the confidence level and accuracy of the estimation when the query is simple. But it's still an estimate, so for more complex queries it might be totally wrong, too, even with high confidence.